# RewriteCond and RewriteRule exclude specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using the following `.htacces` file in my domain root.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|admin|cache)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

One problem, is when I try to open the file located at `cache/themes/theme1/global.css`

But for some reasons it doesn't exclude the folder `cache` from the `RewriteRule`

Anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure that it's mod_rewrite not excluding the request and not a relative URI issue?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this but should work;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(cache.*)$ $1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|admin|cache)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```